# speed reference vs by value

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

i have following question. I tried assignment by value and by reference and as stated [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) assignment ba value should be faster although when I tried my code it gave me a rather mixed results, as sometimes assign1 is faster, sometimes assign2.

```
    class MyAddress{
    char *name;
    long int number;
    char *street;
    char *town;
    char state[2];
    long zip;
    std::vector<int> v_int;
public:
    MyAddress(int i){
        v_int.resize(1000000);
        std::fill(v_int.begin(),v_int.end(),i);
    }
    MyAddress& assign1(MyAddress const& x)
    { 
        MyAddress tmp(x);          // copy construction of tmp does the hard work
        std::swap(*this, tmp);  // trade our resources for tmp's
        return *this;      // our (old) resources get destroyed with tmp 
    }
    MyAddress& assign2(MyAddress x)//x is a copy of the source; hard work already done
    { 
        std::swap(*this, x);  // trade our resources for x's
        return *this;      // our (old) resources get destroyed with x 
    }
};
```

main:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        {
            MyAddress a1(1);
            MyAddress a2(2);
            MyAddress a3(3);
            clock_t tstart=std::clock();
            a1.assign1(a2);
            a1.assign1(a3);
            clock_t tend=std::clock();
            float time_elapsed=((float)tend-(float)tstart);
            std::cout<<std::fixed<<"\nassign1 time elapsed : "<<time_elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }
        {
            MyAddress a1(1);
            MyAddress a2(2);
            MyAddress a3(3);
            clock_t tstart=std::clock();
            a1.assign2(a2);
            a1.assign2(a3);
            clock_t tend=std::clock();
            float time_elapsed=((float)tend-(float)tstart);
            std::cout<<"\nassign2 time elapsed : "<<time_elapsed/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
```

assign1 time elapsed : 0.093000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.094000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.095000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.092000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.109000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.093000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.099000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.094000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.099000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.101000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.096000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.120000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.098000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.105000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.113000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.108000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.111000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.103000

assign1 time elapsed : 0.106000
assign2 time elapsed : 0.106000

I made some changes to the testing code: now I perform 1000 iterations instead of 10.
the results are still mixed: what is specially strange for me is that sometimes first assign is faster but sometimes second:

```
1)
assign1 time elapsed : 111.228996
assign2 time elapsed : 112.097000
2)
assign1 time elapsed : 127.087997
assign2 time elapsed : 126.691002
```

how do you explain this? for me it looks like the result is independent of the value or reference method in this case.

---

finally I have used something like this as I think this is the method suggested [here](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) if I understand it correct

```
MyAddress get_names(MyAddress& ref){return ref;}
```

and now in assign2 it is done this way:

```
a1.assign2(get_names(a2));
a1.assign2(get_names(a3));
```

in fact the performance is slightly better with assign2, at least each time, not interchangeably as before. but is this the difference that I was supposed to see?

```
assign1 time elapsed : 127.087997
assign2 time elapsed : 126.691002

assign1 time elapsed : 137.634995
assign2 time elapsed : 136.054993
```

finally:

```
assign1 time elapsed : 1404.224976
assign2 time elapsed : 1395.886963
```

Comment: Always use the `assign2` version if you want a copy. It's more optimisable, sometimes. Also, are you doing that silly benchmark with optimisations enabled?

Comment: [Want Speed? Pass by Value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: @cf16, you should really read the link above, it explains when and where it might be faster. You might also want to look [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html) for another approach at describing the optimization that can take place. Finally, in C++11 you might want to provide *move* operations (constructor/assignment) to avoid relying on compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your assign functions are basically the same. In one you copy-construct the temporary yourself, while in the other one the copy is automatically injected by the compiler.

Also 10 is not a big enough factor for your testing.

Comment: Except that `assign2` can be better optimized. `a1.assign2(some_function())` can avoid needlessly copying the argument (return value optimization, copy elision, or whatever you like to call it).

Answer (score 1):

For a generic case, 
Assignment by reference should almost always outperform assignment by value.

Reason :

1. Assignment by reference does not create new space on stack
2. It does not have to copy the value from old variable to new variable

The above overhead may be insignificant for most of the programs. However, a const and reference is a general programming practice.

In the current program, 
Both the configurations will perform same.
Try your program with a large number of iterations to see the difference in the timings.

Comment: Irrelevant. Both functions do a copy.

Comment: Assignment by reference can be faster, but not when you create a new copy and assign by `swap`, which should be the default way of doing it, since it is the easiest idiom to get strong exception safety.